# ADO.Net restricting to only select queries

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have an enterprise system with many users. I have this usecase where I let some users to define their own queries to pull reports. When I fire the query, I wrap this around transaction & roll it back so that they dont accidentally delete/corrupt any data.

(ie) I just want to restrict the users to select queries. Is there a better solution ?

I use SQL Server & ADO.Net/PetaPoco.

Comment: Ug (but I understand). You could parse it and look for keywords like update/delete/merge/exec/execute/BCP/xp_cmdshell/;/chr(10)/chr(13)/etc. NOTE: BCP cant be rolled back depending on what they do and xp_cmdshell is outside the current context so it wont be rolled back. Ug!

Comment: Test the SQL with a SQL User that has only read permission and if it fails, don't let them do whatever they do with it (save it somewhere I assume)